# Efficiently extracting information from a pandas dataframe based on two column values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract information from a data frame which is indexed by productId and customerId. I have a large number (millions) of (productId, customerId) pairs and am interested in finding the most efficient way possible to do this.

I have two data frames, df1 containing the customerId, productId pairs I'm interested in, and a second frame df2 containing information of interest which is indexed by customerId, productId pairs.

So far I have tried something like:

```
def f(x, y):
    return(df2.col[(df2.customerId == x) & (df2.productId == y)].sum())

values = df1.apply(lambda x: f(x.customerId, x.productId), axis = 1)
```

which works fine but is very slow.

Any suggestions on improvements?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a list comprehension:

```
values = [df2.loc[df2[['customerId', 'productId']].eq(i).all(), 'col'].sum() for i in df1.values]
```

Comment: I tried this and it is slightly slower - 14.7 seconds for 200 rows vs 13.7 seconds for the original method. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: @ConorMcCabe Edited try again

Comment: @d-n-n Edited again

Comment: @d-n-n Edited again

Comment: OK, if faster in full real data let me know, I upvote answer.

Comment: @d-n-n Try again

Comment: This latest version isn't working for me - what form is df1.values supposed to be, a single column containing customerId, productId pairs?